# How can I run GUI application without login window session?

Tags: .net, user-interface, windows-services

My goal is logout current session, then delete the running local user profile. And I have a service to delete the profile already.

My problem is, the user has no idea about the background service and who may power off the machine or login again too soon.

The idea is that the service will show some popup, and it will not display "Welcome to Windows" until background job finish.

I have read some tricks to run GUI application without login, but I cannot find how to it.

How can it be done on Windows XP and Vista?

Another idea came from my boss is that "Shutdown and install windows update", but execute our apps rather then patch installer.
How to install my application hooks at that point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you are running on a system other than Vista, you will want to replace the GINA dll.  This will give you the proper hooks into the login process to perform your work.

In Vista, you simply won't be able to do this, as GINA was replaced with credential providers, which are not queried when the user logs out.

Also, I see nothing mentioned in your question about what to do if someone logs on the machine through Terminal Services, or through another call to LogonUser.  Deleting the profile when the user logs off is a bad idea, because they might be logged on more than once, so you have to account for that.

Comment: Let me explain a bit more. User profiles are persisted, they can login and logout as usual. But in addition, we need a "Logout and cleanup local profile" button.

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead add the users to the "Guests" group? I believe this stops the profile being persisted beyond their session, although this might be something in poledit instead.

Comment: No. The user profile profile has to be persisted beyond their session.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried anything like this, but I think you should be able to put your popup application in a logoff script that you define in group policy (use gpedit.msc).

I would be interested to hear if this works for you for my own edification so let us know.